# Using ETags to serve rarely updated JS from a CDN

Tags: javascript, caching, web, etag

I've developed a client-side library in JS that is embedded on the client using a single `<script>` line.

The library will be hosted on a CDN (99% on Cloudfront). Once in several weeks/months I would like to update the JS with a new version but wouldn't like the hosting clients to update it as well. (Silent version roll out)

How can I make sure the client always gets the latest version and not the cached one (as it will have the same filename)?

I must note that I don't have access to the website that embeds my JS file, just to the CDN.

I heard about etags and conditional get. Would that help? How can it be used if I don't have access to the JS hosting website.

Thanks!

Comment: I've put "cloudfront etag" to the http://google.com and have got heaps of relevant results. Why haven't you done the same before asking?

Comment: because the results weren't really relevant

Comment: are you sure? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomCaching

Comment: My problem is with the client - I don't understand if I need to make changes to the consuming side (and not on Cloudfront side)

Comment: even if you wanted - you could not. Working with `etag` header is completely handled by browser

Comment: ohh. So it means that some browsers might not support this - and thus the etags method will not really work. right?

Comment: It's unlikely that any browser that was released after 2000 does not support it. So, don't worry.